# How to select specific values from a range of numbers in each row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have the following dataframe(df):

```
                       x                     
index     
01:00:00     [0.11, 0.20, 0.23, 0.30]
01:01:00     [1.00, 1.55, 1.60, 1.80]
01:02:00     [2.33, 2.47, 2.58, 2.70]
01:03:00     [3.41, 3.67, 3.84, 3.93]
```

when i try to select a row from the dataframe, it represents it as an array.

```
in:   df['x'].iloc[2]

out:  array([2.33, 2.47, 2.58, 2.70])
```

i want to select values (that are to 1 decimal place) from each range in each row and have the following dataframe:

```
                       x2                     
index     
01:00:00        [0.20, 0.30]
01:01:00        [1.00, 1.60, 1.80]
01:02:00        [2.70]
01:03:00        NaN
```

i am trying to apply a function to each row.

how do i do this?

Note: (if the range does not have a number in 1 decimal place put it as Nan)

Comment: What errors its throwing? What have your tried?

Comment: What is the data type of the values?  If it's `float`, they don't *have* "decimal" places; they have binary representations that approximate the decimal values.  If they're strings, you can check the last digit to be `0`.  However, it appears that your problem is data access; we can't fix your code if we can't see it.

Comment: @Prune its float.

Comment: For float values, you'll have to format to a string with two decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your list-entries to strings and then check if the respective digit is zero:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[[0.11, 0.20, 0.23, 0.30]],
[[1.00, 1.55, 1.60, 1.80]],
[[2.33, 2.47, 2.58, 2.70]],
[[3.41, 3.67, 3.84, 3.93]]], columns=['x'])

def filter_digit(lst):
    return [entry for entry in lst if "{0:.2f}".format(entry)[3] == '0']

df['new_col'] = df['x'].apply(filter_digit)

#Bonus: Filter empty lists:
df['new_col'] = df['new_col'].apply(lambda y: np.nan if len(y)==0 else y)
```

Output:

```
                          x          new_col
0    [0.11, 0.2, 0.23, 0.3]       [0.2, 0.3]
1     [1.0, 1.55, 1.6, 1.8]  [1.0, 1.6, 1.8]
2   [2.33, 2.47, 2.58, 2.7]            [2.7]
3  [3.41, 3.67, 3.84, 3.93]              NaN
```